# Industry specific lingpipe classification training dataset for sentiment analysis

Tags: sentiment-analysis, training-data, lingpipe

I am looking for lingpipe training data-set(classification - Positive, Negative, Neutral) for sentiment analysis of the reviews data for the following industries -

Healthcare (Reviews about doctors, healthcare services)
Restaurants
Hotels
Retail

Can someone guide on any sources which can help me in getting the above mentioned training data-set..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any general-purpose training sets available for most business-related applications areas.  The best you can do is work with a customer that owns the data or try to scrape reviews from web sites;  the original data we used comes from a scrape of Rotten Tomatoes and others have scraped restaurant review sites.